# Finding an orthonormal basis with respect to an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, orthonormal

Let

$A=\left(\begin{array}{lll} 2 & 0 & 1 \\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{array}\right) \in \mathrm{M}_{3}(\mathbb{R})$

(a) Using the matrix $A$, we define $\langle x, x\rangle:=x^{t} \cdot A \cdot x \geq 0$, where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$. Show that this defines an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

The problem for me in (a) is just showing $\langle x, x\rangle:=x^{t} \cdot A \cdot x \geq 0$

So let $ x = \left(\begin{array}{l} x_1 \\\ x_2 \\\ x_3 \end{array} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$

I end up with $2x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 + 2x_3^2 + 2x_1x_3 \geq 0 $ What's the argument that it's greater or equal to 0. I tried applying some binomial formulas for 2 and 3 variables but I ended up nowhere.

(b) Starting from the standard basis $\left(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3} \right)$, determine an orthonormal basis $\left(f_{1}, f_{2}, f_{3}\right)$ for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with respect to the inner product defined in part (a).

Note that

$\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle =e_1^{t} \cdot A \cdot e_1 = 2 \\\ \langle e_1, e_2 \rangle =e_1^{t} \cdot A \cdot e_2 = 0 \\\ \langle e_2, e_3 \rangle =e_2^{t} \cdot A \cdot e_3 = 0 \\\ \langle e_1, e_3 \rangle =e_1^{t} \cdot A \cdot e_3 = 1 \\\ \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle =e_2^{t} \cdot A \cdot e_2 = 2$

for future calculations.

Now I want to solve this with Gram-Schmidt-Orthonormalization.

The first vector already has length $1$ so $e_1 = f_1$.

Since $f_2 = e_2 - \frac{\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle}{\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle} \cdot e_1$ and $\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle = 0$, so $f_2 = e_2.$

The third vector

$f_3= e_3 - \frac{\langle e_1, e_3 \rangle}{\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle} \cdot e_1 - \frac{\langle e_2, e_3 \rangle}{\langle e_2, e_2 \rangle} \cdot e_2 = e_1 - 0.5 \cdot e_1 = \left( \begin{array}{l} -0.5 \\\ 0 \\\ 1 \end{array} \right)$

Normalizing:

$f_3^{*} = \frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}\left( \begin{array}{l} -0.5 \\\ 0 \\\ 1 \end{array} \right)$

But $f_3^{*} $ isn't orthogonal to the first basis vector. I tried finding the error for hours now.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $$2x_1^2+2x_2^2+2x_3^2+2x_1x_3=x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2+(x_1+x_3)^2$$

Comment: The matrix is symmetric with eigenvalues $1,2,3$ hence it is positive definite.

Comment: Note that $\langle e_2,e_2\rangle=2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks! But this still doesn't help with the orthogonality of the $e_1$ and $f_3^{*}$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP found the mistake.